# Disable full screen youtube video display using UIWebView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, youtube

I'm using UIWebView to play youtube videos on iPhone. When the video is loaded it displayed on full screen mode and hide all my view. The view have a label for header on top of UIWebview
When I click done button, I noticed that my view is shifted down a bit leaving white space on top of the view. I don't know how to fix this so I was thinking to disable full screen mode.
I would appreciate any help if you can tell me why the view is shifted down or how to disable 
full screen mode.
Thanks in advance,
Sarah

Comment: This looks like a similar question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser
Which does have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, the YouTube video player on the iPhone will always go full screen.

If you can get the URL of H264 version on you tube you can use the [Media Player framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006952) for playback.