# Is it possible to avoid the native video players on mobile devices?

Tags: android, iphone, html

I am trying to play video through a webview on my Android and iPhone device. I would like the video to play and have some text displayed below it. Is it possible for me to play a video and not have the device switch into full-screen mode?

I am using the video tag in HTML5. My target platforms are iOS 5 and Android 2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

android does not support **inline**-html5-video before **version 3.1** - no chance before that.
iOS 4+ does support it when you add this:

HTML

```
<video id="player" width="480" height="320" webkit-playsinline>
```

the important part is the added attribute **webkit-playsinline**. It is required for **iPads** to be able to play videos inline **in the browser**.

Obj-C

```
webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

The Obj-C code is required for iPhone/iPod. As of now they don't support inline video in the browser but with this line of code in your container-app it works in the webview

PS: copied the code-snippets from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767927/818732

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the playback by *skimming* the video instead of actually `.play()`'ing it, which is what starts the fullscreen.

I wrote a module that takes care of **playing the video inline** and synchronizing it to the audio (but it also works on videos without a sound track): [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video)

The iPhone and iPod now seem just about the only devices/browsers that force fullscreen video playback in Safari (and in apps that make use of its unmodified WebView). I couldn't find a recent Android device that would force the video fullscreen.