# WebKit Cocoa can't change video scale

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I can change scale of my simple page in safari by cmd+"+"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls src='../videos/video.mp4'>
</video>
/body>
</html>
```

but can't change it in WebView by:

```
id doc = [[[self.web mainFrame] frameView] documentView];
[doc scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(0.5, 0.5)];
[doc setNeedsDisplay];
```

the video disappears for all scales except 1.0. Why?

in console: "`FlateDecode: decoding error: incorrect data check.`"

**SOLVED IN HTML**

i've added zoom line in my html tag

and video scale now is ok

maybe someone knows how to solve it in cocoa webkit

Answer (score 0):

Checkout these links

- [HTML5 inline video on iPhone vs iPad/Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser)
- [iPhone plays embedded video fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459859/iphone-plays-embedded-video-fullscreen)

hope it helps