# forcing a video linked by an anchor to play fullscreen on an iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, vimeo

Is there a way to force a video to play full screen on the iPad?

I have a basic anchor which has the link to Vimeo, however this opens in the browser window - rather than full screen.

```
<a href="http://vimeo.com/videourl.mp4">
   <p>watch the film</p>
</a>
```

I've had a look around StackOverflow and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser) shows how to go the *other* way and force it to play inline, rather than full-screen. But I don't see an option to reverse this.

I am testing on an iPad 2 running iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function addFullscreenButton() {

        if (vid.webkitSupportsFullscreen) {

            var fs = document.getElementById("fs");

            fs.style.visibility = "visible";

        }

    }

    function goFullscreen() {

        vid.webkitEnterFullscreen();

    }
```

html5:

```
<video src="myMovie.m4v" id="myVideo" autoplay controls></video>
<input type="button" id="fs" value="Fullscreen" onclick="goFullscreen()" style="visibility:hidden">
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html