# Disable fullscreen iphone video

Tags: iphone, ios, html, video, canvas

Struggling with this problem for a few days in a row now...

Is there any way or 'hack' to disable playing video fullscreen on Safari on a iPhone. Of course I already tried the 'webkit-playsinline' attribute, but this will only work in your own app.

See:

```
<video class="" poster="" webkit-playsinline>
    <source src="" type="video/ogg" preload="auto">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4" preload="auto">                
</video>
```

Also I've tried to put the video on canvas, but as it looks video as a source for the canvas drawImage() method is not currently supported on iOS.

Is there any other way or alternative technique I can use? Or did I really waste my time the last few days?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser

Answer (score 82):

You will need the [playsinline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#playsinline) attribute:

```
<video src="file.mp4" playsinline></video>
```

If you're using JSX in a React component, the first letter of `Inline` is uppercase:

```
<video src="file.mp4" playsInline/>
```

---

This attribute has been available since 2016. If you're reading this from year 2015, there's [an alternative option](https://github.com/fregante/iphone-inline-video).

Comment: For me, `<video src="file.mp4" playsinline>` made it inline, but `webkit-playsinline` attribute alone didn't work.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: @Carlene I think you wanted to write `playsinline` and not `playinline` nor `playinine`, is it correct ?

Comment: Oh dear! Good catch @RaphaëlBalet yes it's playsinline

Comment: @Carlene could you correct it then please :) it may help others. Even if I tested it on IOS 14 and it doesn't seems to work anymore ;(

Comment: Don't be a muppet like me and forget that if using react, you have to use `playsInline` instead of `playsinline`. Trap for young players...

Answer (score 20):

```
    <div id="video-player">
        <video src="http://movies.apple.com/media/us/html5/showcase/2011/demos/apple-html5-demo-tron-us_848x352.m4v"></video>
        <p><a href="javascript:playPause();">Play/Pause</a></p>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        // intercept and cancel requests for the context menu
        var myVideo = document.querySelector('video');
        myVideo.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); }, false);

        // hide the controls if they're visible
        if (myVideo.hasAttribute("controls")) {
            myVideo.removeAttribute("controls")   
        }

        // play/pause functionality
        function playPause() {
            if (myVideo.paused)
                myVideo.play();
            else
                myVideo.pause();
         }

         // essentially you'll have to build your own controls ui
         // for position, audio, etc.

    </script>
```

The idea is to:

1. Prevent the user getting to the context menu (to show the controls)
2. Hide any player controls that might be visible

The downside is that you have to implement your own player UI - but it's not too complicated

*This code is only intended to show you how to solve the problem, not for use in a live application

A bit more research on the subject finds:

> **webkit-playsinline** Indicates that a video element should play in-line
>   instead of full-screen.
>
> Related Tags “video” Availability Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>   (Enabled *only in a UIWebView* with the allowsInlineMediaPlayback
>   property set to YES.
>   [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-SW30)

I'm afraid it just not going to be possible using the video player in Safari

They have a guide for Video on Canvas, but as you probably know it isn't supported in IOS yet: [video on canvas](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/PuttingVideoonCanvas/PuttingVideoonCanvas.html)

This document summarises the current restrictions around mobile media content in IOS: [mobile video status](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

Comment: Also this resulted in a fullscreen playback. Though I definitely see the idea behind it.

Comment: I noticed on my Windows Phone that video always plays fullscreen - I have no choice in the matter, it may not be possible through a browser - why do you need this behaviour? (there might be a different approach)

Comment: Certain elements within the website have to be triggered on specific timecodes.

Answer (score 4):

just add 'playsinline':

in javascript:

```
yourclassName.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
```

in html:

```
<video class="Vidoo" src="https://.../video.mp4" playsinline></video>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't be a muppet like me and forget that if using react, you have to use playsInline instead of playsinline. Trap for young players...

```
<video class="" poster="" playsInline webkit-playsInline>
    <source src="" type="video/ogg" preload="auto">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4" preload="auto">                
</video>
```

Comment: The documentation says to use small letter `i` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-SW30)

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that iOS always plays video full screen. On Apple's own website they used encoded image data and Javascript drawing to do video-like playback. Here is a breakdown of how they did it:

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1GWTMLjqQsQS45FWwqNG9ztQTdGF48hQYpjQHR_d1WsI

Comment: This may have changed since 2013. I've seen more "in-place" video playback, so maybe iOS 8 supported it now.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue while developing a mobile app using react native. My solution was easy/stressful.
If you are using Webview, this is my solution. Also, something to mention, **If you are using low power mode on an ios device**, you cannot autoplay a video. There is a function of some sort to get by it but for now, this will work.

```
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
<WebView
    style={styles.container}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
    source={{
      html: `
      <video
      id = "video"
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;"
      poster="" width="50%" height="50%" muted=" loop="" playsinline
      autoplay>
      <source src="https://aparissi.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/SplashVideo-1.mp4">
      <source>
    </video>
    `,
    }}
  />
```

In react native webview, there a property named "**allowsInLineMediaPlayback**". Set it to true! You also must have **playsinline** inside the video tag aswell. Another thing to mention was that you **cannot auto-play a video if you don't have the muted property** either.
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by using the mp4 video as the preloader "poster".

my code:

```
<video poster="/path/to/video.mp4" autoplay loop muted webkit-playsinline playsinline type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I just wanted a mp4 to be displayed as a GIF... I realized that the preloader itself was working perfectly.
And.. to prevent a possible future failure with other browsers, I just added a condition to check if the current browser is a iOS browser, if yes, then I use this non sense work around, otherwise, I use the normal video tag with SRC and a preload gif on the "poster" parameter.

Comment: I just want to say that this worked PERCETLY, like a charm! Even better than I could ever imagine, because as I am using cordova and ALL my .mp4 files are locally on the app itself, there is 0 delay. As soon as the page loads (less than a second) the "mp4 as git" starts looping