# Prevent fullscreen video on iOS cordova web app

Tags: ios, cordova, quasar, cordova-ios

I've been stuck for some hours now. I need my app to be able to play a video without going in fullscreen with iOS. I've tried both `playsinline` and `webkit-playsinline` and none is working. I'm using quasar framework and cordova to compile the app for iOS. This is my video tag:

```html
<video ref="videoRef" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 50%" src="" id="video-container" playsinline controls/>
```

**Notes:**

`src` tag si empty because I'm making the user select a local file and later playing it in the video tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable fullscreen iphone video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521667/disable-fullscreen-iphone-video)

Comment: @Eric sadly it doesn't... As you can see in the tag I wrote I have already written the `playsinline` attribute and it doesn't work

Comment: one answer states that you have to set playsinline ="true" and not set it twice....

Comment: @Eric I've tried `playsinline="true"` and nothing... Keeps the same

Comment: You can find the solution for this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407488/inline-youtube-video-doesnt-work-in-cordova-application-on-ios/76368966#76368966