# How to play a video in inline of iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, html5-video, css

I try to play a video in html5 video tag for my iOS app. When I play the video in my app its open in a quick time player with full screen. How to play a video inline of video tag without open the full screen. Any one give me solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the stream url use MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to add MPMoviePlayerController in my html page to play video

Answer (score 0):

create a UIView. Init a MPMoviePlayerController. set the contentURL to the video URL. Add the MPMoviePlayerController as a subview to the view you want in your app.

Comment: I tried it and works great. But I want to add MPMoviePlayerController in my html page to play video. Is it possible? Or any other ways?

Comment: Check this link out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser

Comment: thanks works fine. But when I trying to get multiple videos from JSON. I got [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 1) in console. Why it stops playing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution. Adding `<video src="" allowfullscreen width="280" height="280" webkit-playsinline loop></video>`

then use

```
htmlview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
htmlview.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

in my .m file viewdidload function.