# Force full-screen HTML5 video playback on iPad and Android tablets?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, html5-video, fullscreen

I have a simple video tag:

```
<video id="video-1" poster="img/video/poster-1.jpg" preload="none">
  <source src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/the_video-id" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I play it via a javascript button

```
$('[data-play-video]').click(function(){
  var video_id = $(this).data('playVideo');
  var video_control = $(video_id)[0];
  video_control.play();
});
```

The video plays inline on the desktop and in the full-screen player on iPhone. On iPad it plays inline, but I want it to play full-screen in the default iOS video player—the same as on the iPhone. How can I achieve this?

I am aware of the `webkit-playsinline` attribute which may be used to force the video to play inline on the iPhone. ([HTML5 inline video on iPhone vs iPad/Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser)) and ([Can I avoid the native fullscreen video player with HTML5 on iPhone or android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054560/can-i-avoid-the-native-fullscreen-video-player-with-html5-on-iphone-or-android))

I, however, want the opposite: to play the video in the default-for-iPhone full-screen format on all iOS and Android devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use webkitEnterFullscreen() method.

```
    var vid;

    function init() {

        vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

        vid.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", addFullscreenButton, false);

    }

    function addFullscreenButton() {

        if (vid.webkitSupportsFullscreen) {

            var fs = document.getElementById("fs");

            fs.style.visibility = "visible";

        }

    }

    function goFullscreen() {

        vid.webkitEnterFullscreen();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I used `video_conrol.webkitEnterFullscreen();` and it seems to work on the iPad!