# UIWebView to play Html 5 video without going to Video Player of iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiwebview

I want to use video player technique used in my website. I use html 5 videos in website and send normal URL to app so that they can be played using the native MPMoviePlayerController inside the app. Now I have requirements where I want to use the same technique as web inside the app as UIWebView. When I request the link to load, it opens up the default player view of iOS, which I want to avoid.

Can this be possible?

Comment: As per bellow SO posts you can by tweaking html5 video attributes and by natvice code.

 `HTML 5 : <video id="player" width="480" height="320" webkit-playsinline>`

And

`objc or swift : webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;`

"Credits  : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser"

Comment: Let me know if this works.

Comment: @amorbytes..Actually I am not from the web background so I don't know what to write when loading the URL in WebView..If you could make an example, then that would be better

Lets say I want to play 
http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v

Comment: have you control over html content?

Comment: if so then post your html content here.

Comment: @Saty I think that it is only possible with iPads

Comment: I tried with phonegap inline html5 video in iphone and it just works. so it may be done with help of this code.

Comment: can you send me the code of the url

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. Not in the Safari browser. Videos will always be played by the native player. Trust me, I've spent a lot of time on this.

If you build a Phonegap app, it is possible by what is mentioned here:

[HTML5 inline video on iPhone vs iPad/Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser?lq=1)

Basically:

HTML

`<video id="player" width="480" height="320" webkit-playsinline>`

Obj-C

`webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;`

Comment: @Paul...I am trying this technique in webpage and trying to play it in Chrome in iPod and still it is switching to native player

Comment: Video cannot be played inline on an iOS device. If someone is able to, then it is a hack. If you want to play video inline, then you have to create an app. Either Phonegap or Native.

Comment: @Paul.....I am talking about the WebView in native app. is there any way totally remove the native player?

Comment: No, you cannot remove the native player. You can, however, play the video inline using the code example I gave above in a WebView.

Comment: Is this still the case? "You cannot stop safari/iphone browser using native player?" Shame as I wanted to use Cloudflare Stream HTML5 video player embedded <stream></stream> but iOS video takes over everytime...